# Embed external video using Url Link in asp.net webpage

Tags: asp.net

I have my external url link of a video in my sql server.How do I embed that video using my url link in asp.net page? Any suggestions will be helpfull.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/files,-images,-and-media/10-working-with-video).
Basically, If those are youtube videos, you can do with code like this:

```
    <iframe width="560" 
            height="315" 
            src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/fxCEcPxUbYA" 
            frameborder="0" 
            allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In other cases, you can [install a specific Helper](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/installing-helpers) to assist you.